# Installing Ubuntu-Linux on Virtualbox (Virtual Machine)

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

I downloaded virtualbox for mac and the Ubuntu Linux iso. I have tried to install the iso on a virtual machine I set up using virtualbox. I keep getting this message,

```
[ 7.409131] Kernel panic -not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) 
[7.409989] atkbd serio0: Spurious ACK on isa0060/serio0. Some program might be trying to access hardware directly.
```

What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Maybe the iso is corrupted. Please [check the MD5 checksum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the iso file. If it doesn't match, then download the iso again.

Comment: And add information about the host and the guest hardware

Answer (score 0):

This message "VFS: Unable to mount root fs" means that you root fs has a filesystem type that is not recognized by kernel at boot time. To solve this, you need to enable appropriate modules at boot time. Tips [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-kernel-panic-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-and-solution/).

Answer (score 0):

I have a sony vaio fit flip 13 (SVF13N), currently running ubuntu 20.04, and have had this "keyboard broken on resume from suspend" issue on and off for about the last 4 years, its infuriating. Anyway, it seemed to disappear on ubuntu 19.10, but after upgrading to 20 it was back, also introducing the issue that frequently when putting the machine to sleep initially, it would come straight back up again.

In my dmesg log after resume from suspend, it would have the following

```
[  386.346990] i8042: Can't write CTR while closing AUX port
[  386.861197] i8042: Can't reactivate AUX port
[  386.864025] atkbd serio0: Spurious ACK on isa0060/serio0. Some program might be trying to access hardware directly.
```

It turned out the first two lines of that log were not really an issue, and googling them led to a lot of red-herrings. After adding

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.dumbkbd"
```

to /etc/default/grub, rerunning update-grub, and restarting my computer the problem went away.